# Setting default value of a checkbutton in a menu to True

Tags: python, tkinter

**Goal**

I am creating a menu inside an application. In that I want a radiobutton. And by default I want the radiobutton, to be in the `on` state.

**Research**

I found how to add the radiobutton using the `options.add_radiobutton()` command here
 [TKinter effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm) . But I still don't know which of the options needs to be used so that in the default it is set to on.

**Code**

```
optionsmenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)

optionsmenu.add_radiobutton(label='Pop Up set to on??',command=self.togglePopUp)
```

code for `self.togglePopUp`:

```
def togglePopUp(self,event=None):
    if self.showPopUp:
        self.showPopUp = False

    else:
        self.showPopUp = True
```

I will initialise `self.showPopUp` as `True`.

**Please** Help me with setting the radiobutton to the `on` position in the default mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to toggle boolean values, I suggest you to use `add_checkbutton()` instead of `add_radiobutton()`.

With the radiobutton you only have a static `value` option, which does not change when the entry is clicked. On the other hand, checkbuttons allow you to change between the `onvalue` and `offvalue` options.

```
self.var = IntVar(root)
self.var.set(1)
optionsmenu.add_checkbutton(label='Pop Up set to on??', command=self.togglePopUp,
                            variable=self.var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
```

Note that the IntVar you have to use as variable for the meny entry can replace the `self.togglePopUp` variable.

Comment: What is the difference between a `checkbutton` and a `radiobutton`??

Comment: @IcyFlame: checkbuttons are usually square, radiobuttons are usually round. Checkbuttons are for selecting 0-n of a set of values. The set can be just one item. Radiobuttons are for picking exactly one value from a set of choices. the set should always contain at least two choices.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @A Rodas:

```
self.var = IntVar()

self.var.set(1)

optionsmenu.add_checkbutton(label='Pop Up set to on??', command=self.togglePopUp,
                            variable=self.var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
```

And to get back the value of this variable use:

```
if self.var.get() == 1:
    self.showpopup()

else:

    print 'popup has been disabled. you can toggle this option in the options menu'
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way according to me is to initialize the variable with a default value of 1.

```
var = IntVar(value=1)
```